# Primefaces global css font issue?

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using below css to change the font size of every component of primefaces

```
 .ui-widget{
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 90% !important;
}
```

But its look like something not working ,Wizard tab font size is very big,While Button very small. Can some please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... looks the other way around... ;-). Use the browser developer tool and css what css **is** applied and add an additional rule. All basic css

Comment: Agree but what is the use of creating global css if i have to make changes for every component again?

Comment: Where does it say every component? And if you investigate and find a cause for this behaviour, you can report it and they might fix it. Not everyone is perfect you know